# Weird behavior in my mesh when trying to move it in Edit Mode

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, transforms

In this gif, I'm simply trying to move the mesh by pressing  <kbd>G</kbd>. The very left of the mesh refuses to move past the x axis, while the rest of the mesh moves fine. What is happening?
[image]

Comment: Nvm, i just figured it out. There must be a shortcut to activate mirroring. I had the X axis on mirror. Turning it off fixed it.

Comment: you can write an own answer for that if you want - so others might learn something from it as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There must be a shortcut to activate mirroring in Edit Mode. I guess I accidentally activated it. i went into the "Active Tool and Workspace settings" on the right hand side and clicked the "Options" dropdown and disabled the mirroring that was activated, in my instance it was activated on the X axis.